# What is the current (June 2018) recommended target in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am not sure what the current (June 2018) recommended target is for TS compilation - ES5, ES6?

As far as I understand it, ES5 is fully supported by all main browsers, while ES6 is mostly supported by  the main browsers.

Comment: I wouldn't say there's a agreed 'recommended' target - it depends entirely on which browsers you have to support and which features you're using.

Comment: Use the target that works with all of your target browsers.

Comment: @mikemccaughan Great example of NOT rolling out the welcome mat.  A legitimate question gets legitimate answers, and even after the answer is accepted it is "Put on Hold as too broad."  Actually, it is a very specific question and there is no logical reason to put it on hold. Notice no-one has actually offered any advice or actual comment as to exactly how to make it more specific, or in any way improve the question which WOULD be rolling out the welcome mat. In other words, putting the question on hold is not actually helping SO or anyone else, so what is the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES3 is default (hence recommended) and I don't see why you want to change that? Elaborate please. If you are not experiencing any difficulties the answer is simply: Do not change it.

There are no special preferences. If you are working in an environment which requires you (for whatever reason) to target a specific ES version, then target it. But this question is not generally answerable.

Protip: You can also use http://caniuse.com to see the current status of browsers' es implementation. Simply search for ES5, ES6, ES2017 and so on. As you can see you might block Opera Mini with ES5 and IE with ES6. So if you want to support all platforms possible ES5/6 wouldn't be the way to go.